# Perform multiple SUMs on same column but for multiple date range periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Given the following table:

```
id   member_id    paid_amount    trx_date
-------------------------------------------
x    1            100            2019-07-01
x    2             50            2019-07-02
x    1            150            2019-07-05
x    2             70            2019-07-08
x    1             90            2019-08-01
```

I would like to partition this data and get the sum for each member in 30 day intervals starting at the day of query execution and going backwards. My end result should look like this if I execute the query on the **10th** of the month:

```
member_id  paid_amount  from
----------------------------------
1          250          2019-06-10 (Sum of paid_amount from 06-10 to 07-10 for member 1)
2          120          2019-06-10 (Sum of paid_amount from 06-10 to 07-10 for member 2)
1           90          2019-07-10 (Sum of paid_amount from 07-10 to 08-10 for member 1)
```

Basically I would like to sum `paid_amount` depending on the date where the query ran, in this example **10th Sep 2019**, so I want the sum for each member for the following periods

```
2019-08-10 --> 2019-09-10
2019-07-10 --> 2019-08-10
2019-06-10 --> 2019-07-10
2019-05-10 --> 2019-06-10
etc..
```

This is what I came up with so far:

```sql
SELECT 
    member_id, 
    SUM(paid_amount), 
    p 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        member_id,
        paid_amount,
        CASE WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE() THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -8, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -8, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             WHEN trx_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -9, GETUTCDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -8, GETUTCDATE()) THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -9, GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
             -- and many more WHEN clauses ...
        END AS p
    FROM
        my_table
    ) AS t
GROUP BY 
    t.member_id,
    t.p
```

While the above works, there are a few problems with it. First, I need to define so many `WHEN` clauses because I don't know how far the data goes back to. The second issue is that this query starts slowing down a bit when my table is large.

I am using this query for a view so some options are off limit. Is there a better version of this that is smaller and possibly offer better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the date periods that cover all the data in your table:

```
WITH md (min_trx_date) AS (
SELECT MIN(trx_date) AS min_trx_date FROM my_table
),
cte (trx_date_end, trx_date_start) AS (
SELECT convert(date, GETUTCDATE()) AS trx_date_end, 
       convert(date, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETUTCDATE())) AS trx_date_start
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, trx_date_end),
       DATEADD(MONTH, -1, trx_date_start)
FROM cte
JOIN md ON cte.trx_date_start > md.min_trx_date
)
```

and then `JOIN` that CTE to your table to get the payments:

```
SELECT m.member_id, 
       SUM(m.paid_amount),
       cte.trx_date_start
FROM my_table m
JOIN cte ON m.trx_date BETWEEN cte.trx_date_start AND cte.trx_date_end
GROUP BY member_id, trx_date_start
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aded2be74af50968ccbd8bb60181d351)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *cte recursive* make calendar table.

use LEAD get next month date, then do `join` with table.

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT CAST('2019-01-10' AS DATE) fromDt,  
         CAST('2019-12-10' AS DATE) toDt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateadd(month,1,fromDt),toDt
  FROM CTE
  WHERE dateadd(month,1,fromDt) < toDt
),CTE2 AS(
  SELECT fromDt,LEAD(fromDt) OVER(ORDER BY fromDt) nextMonth
  FROM CTE 
) 
SELECT member_id,
    fromDt,
    SUM(paid_amount) paid_amount
FROM CTE2 c JOIN T t 
on t.trx_date BETWEEN c.fromDt and c.nextMonth
GROUP BY member_id,fromDt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f16c3/8/0)**:

```
| member_id |     fromDt | paid_amount |
|-----------|------------|-------------|
|         1 | 2019-06-10 |         250 |
|         2 | 2019-06-10 |         120 |
|         1 | 2019-07-10 |          90 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your function computing p with something simpler, like `datediff(day, trx_date, getutcdate()) / 30`. First 30-day interval backwards from now will produce value 0, second - 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Select member_id, paid_amount, trx_date as from  from TABLE 
a join Table b where DateDiff(a.trx_date, b.trx_date) =30
 group by member _id

Comment: Code only answers without any explanation aren't very helpful. Please consider adding more detail into why your answer works / what it does.